# Pygame - Wait for animation to finish

Tags: animation, pygame

I have made a `Button` class that basically draws a `Rect` object and a text if specified and I implemented an animation that basically shrinks the button and inflates it back quickly on click

```
class Button:
    def __init__(self, surface, pos, size, bg_color, hover_color):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x, self.y = pos[0], pos[1]
        self.width, self.height = size[0], size[1]
        self.bgColor = bg_color
        self.hoverColor = hover_color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, size)
        self.text = None
        self.clicked = False
    
    def addText(self, font, text, txt_color):
        self.text = font.render(text, True, txt_color)
        self.textRect = self.text.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

    def update(self):
        if self.isHovered():
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.hoverColor, self.rect, border_radius=20)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.bgColor, self.rect, border_radius=20)

        if(self.text):
            self.surface.blit(self.text, self.textRect)

        self.checkClicked()

    def checkClicked(self):
        if(self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
            if(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]):
                if(not self.clicked):
                    self.clicked = True
                    self.rect.inflate_ip(-7, -7)
            else:
                if(self.clicked):
                    self.clicked = False
                    self.rect.inflate_ip(7, 7)
                    
    def isHovered(self):
        return True if self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) else False
```

It's probably not the most effecient way to do it, but I'll worry about that later.

The implementation then would be :

```
startBtn = Button(display, (100, 160), (200, 40), (40, 40, 40), (70, 70, 70))
run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            elif (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
                if(startBtn.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                    showNextScreen() # Here lies the issue
                    print('pressed')
        display.fill((50, 50, 50))
        startBtn.update()
        pygame.display.update()
```

I have a function that would draw a new screen and bascially starts the game, however it happens too quick that you can't see the animation of the button and I am struggling to find a way to let the script wait for the button animation to finish then do stuff, I have tried `pygame.time.wait()` and `pygame.time.delay()` but the whole script freezes and makes it worse, How could I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to achieve this, again it might not be the optimal way to do it but it does the job :

Importing `Timer` from `threading` to create a timer and passing the function that would draw the next screen/scene as an argument to delay it for some milliseconds does the trick.

```
#up in the script
from threading import Timer
import pygame

#then some code goes here
.
.
.
def showNextScreen():
    #code related to the next screen goes here

startBtn = Button(display, (100, 160), (200, 40), (40, 40, 40), (70, 70, 70))
run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            elif (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
                if(startBtn.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                    t = Timer(0.3, showNextScreen) #Timer(seconds, function)
                    t.start() #starts the timer and once its over it calls the function passed
                    #giving the button animation enough time to fully finish.
                    print('pressed')
        display.fill((50, 50, 50))
        startBtn.update()
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `time.sleep()`

Comment: `time.sleep()` isn't good for GUIs because it completely delays the program, causing the window to not respond.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function called `sleep` that waits a given amount of time without freezing the game.

## Function

```
def sleep(ms): # ms --> time in milliseconds
    start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)

        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - start == ms:
            running = False
```

## Explanation

It takes one parameter: `ms`, which is the amount of time that you want the program to wait in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds). In the function, I set a variable called `start` to `pygame.time.get_ticks()`, which returns the current time. Then, inside a while loop, I created an event loop which checks for the `pygame.QUIT` event so that if the user clicks `X` while the function is still running, the program will respond and quit the program. After the event loop, I set a variable called `now` to `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get the current time. Then I checked if `now` (the current time) subtracted by `start` (the start time) is equal to `ms` (the given amount of waiting time in milliseconds). This checks if the given amount of time has passed. If it has, the while loop ends. If not, the while loop keeps running until that condition is `True`.

Comment: Well explained and a nice workaround, thanks for your answer but implementing this in my case didn't really solve the issue, probably the way I animated the button makes this a bit tricky.

Comment: @Sh00tthem, no problem. I’m glad to hear you managed to find a solution :)