# How can I make python wait for a specified amount of time before moving to the next line?

Tags: python, time

This is my code currently.

```
def attack(self, surface, target):
        attacking_rect = pygame.Rect(self.rect.centerx - (2*self.rect.width*self.flip), self.rect.y, 2*self.rect.width, self.rect.height)
        if attacking_rect.colliderect(target.rect) and self.char_type == 'Player':
            time.sleep(.9) #wait for animation to finish
            target.health -= random.randint(7, 15)
            target.hit = True
        elif attacking_rect.colliderect(target.rect) and self.char_type == 'Skeleton':
            time.sleep(1.4) #wait for animation to finish
            target.health -= random.randint(6, 10)
            target.hit = True
```

Doing my first pygame project this is another issue I ran into. The issue here is that time pauses my whole program whereas I only want to pause this function from moving to the next line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pygame - Wait for animation to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70824142/pygame-wait-for-animation-to-finish)

Comment: Maybe I'm not implementing the solutions in that post properly but they seem to all freeze my whole program which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider multithreading,.

Why don't you open a new thread for every time you run `attack(self, surface, target)`, and then pause just the thread instead of making your whole program hang?

Check out [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) for the `threading` library as well as [this guide](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-threading/) for more information on how to actually use `threading`.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct behaviour and it will freeze your whole application because there is only one main thread that is handling your code. In this case the only way will be as Ryan suggested, will be using the multithreading